# Yajra DataTable Is Not Installing on Laravel 5.7.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, yajra-datatable

I am facing problem while installing Yajra Datatable by using this Command " composer require yajra/laravel-datatables:^1.0 "on Powershell and I got errors. I have Uninstall Wampp and installed Xampp but the problem still exists. Please Help me out to figure out why this is happening is any PHP version issue or something else. I am solving this issue from two days to since now but I failed.

**Code snippet of problem**

Problem 1

- Installation request for yajra/laravel-datatables 1.0 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables[v1.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.7.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
- yajra/laravel-datatables v1.0.0 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons 3.* -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.3.0].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons 3.0.x-dev requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.0 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.1 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.0.2 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.1.0 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.1.1 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.1.2 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5. -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.2.0 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.2.1 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.2.2 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons v3.3.0 requires illuminate/console 5.4.|5.5.|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- don't install illuminate/console 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
- don't install illuminate/console v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.7.12, required as 5.7.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.12].

**Here is my Composer.json**

```
{

"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "emotality/tawk-laravel": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.2",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "1.0",

},

"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},

"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

**System details**

Operating System Windows

PHP 7.2.11

Laravel Version 5.7.12

Laravel-Datatables Version ^1.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had this issue, just run this command.

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables
```

should install latest version of the package, or add this line

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.2"
```

to composer.json then run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with updating laravel from 5.7 to 5.8 because of yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle. I removed this package from composer.json, made laravel update with `composer update` and then made `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle`